# Corrupted Windows Update Service Security Registry Key

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-registry

I have a corrupted security key in the registry (Windows XP) for the windows update service.  I noticed that I can copy a security key from another service and move and replace it with the corrupted key.  We have many machines that have this issue.  Can we script this with a security key we know will work or can one machine not have the same security key as another?

Comment: What is the registry key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\wuauserv\Security\Security` value, is that correct? If so, to script it you can:

1. Run the following command on a "working" machine: `sc sdshow wuauserv`
2. Note the output of that command, which will be similar to `D:(A;;CCLCSWRPLORC;;;AU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)`
3. On the "broken" machines, run the following command, replacing `<SDDL>` with the value from step two: `sc sdset wuauserv <SDDL>`

Comment: I would upvote but I am not allowed